# Back button to previous element don't work as imagine

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is a questionnaire to help people where should they go when they have a certain type of ticket.

I'm currently tinkering with the code that have been answered from previous question, and after realizing the answer was a bit off [If you answer "No" on the first question and press "Back" it doesn't go to the first question but goes to the second question about ticket type].

What I'm thinking is if the tab is currently on `id="tab2"` then the `data-value` will be `-2` then else will be `-1`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
    $(".tab a").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
      var tabContents = $(this).attr("href");
      $(tabContents).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
      return false;
    });
  });


  $("button").on("click", function(){
    let currentLevel = $(this).closest('.tab').attr('data-level');
    let prevLevel = parseInt(currentLevel) - 1;
    $('.tab').removeClass("active");
    $('.tab').each(function(index, item) {
      if(parseInt($(item).attr('data-level')) === prevLevel) {
        $(item).addClass('active');
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.question_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.yes_part,
.no_part {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.yes_part {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

a.yes {
  background-color: #FFB8B8;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

a.no {
  background-color: #B1E0FF;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ticket_type {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.ticket_type a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.answer_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />

<section class="question_wrapper">
  <ul class="tab main-tab active animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" data-level='1'>
    <li class="active">
      <p>Do you have a ticket ?</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="yes_part">
          <img src="yes.png" alt="">
          <a class="yes" href="#tab1">yes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="no_part">
          <img src="no.png" alt="">
          <a class="no" href="#tab2">no</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab1" data-level='2'>
    <li>
      <p>Which Ticket do you have ?</p>
      <div class="ticket_type">
        <a href="#tab3">Type 1</a>
        <a href="#tab3">Type 2</a>
        <a href="#tab3">Type 3</a>
        <a href="#tab4">Type 4</a>
        <a href="#tab4">Type 5</a>
        <a href="#tab5">Type 6</a>
      </div>
      <button type="button">Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab2" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <p>Go buy some ticket then</p>
      <button>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab3" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <div class="answer_1">
        <p>Please go to hall A</p>
        <img src="receptionist.png" alt="">
        <button>Back</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab4" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <p>Please go to hall B</p>
      <button>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab5" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <p>Please go to hall C</p>
      <button>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry for the error on the snippet. I revert it back to the last working one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned there were numerous typos, missing `if`s, extra brackets and such in the JS. It's not really valuable to point them all out here. If you like the solution, you can just copy this and work from there. For the back button, I removed a big IF conditional and replaced it with

```
$(`.tab[data-level=${prevLevel}]`).eq(0).addClass('active')
```

Which says *find the first tab with the data-attribute data-level=X and add the class active to it * - and it seems to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tab a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
    var tabContents = $(this).attr("href");
    $(tabContents).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
    return false;
  });

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    let currentLevel = $(this).closest('.tab').attr('data-level');
    let prevLevel = parseInt(currentLevel) - 1;
     $('.tab').removeClass("active");
     $(`.tab[data-level=${prevLevel}]`).eq(0).addClass('active')
  });
});
```

```css
.question_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.yes_part,
.no_part {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.yes_part {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

a.yes {
  background-color: #FFB8B8;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

a.no {
  background-color: #B1E0FF;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ticket_type {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.ticket_type a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.answer_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />

<section class="question_wrapper">
  <ul class="tab main-tab active animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" data-level='1'>
    <li class="active">
      <p>Do you have a ticket ?</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="yes_part">
          <img src="yes.png" alt="">
          <a class="yes" href="#tab1">yes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="no_part">
          <img src="no.png" alt="">
          <a class="no" href="#tab2">no</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab1" data-level='2'>
    <li>
      <p>Which Ticket do you have ?</p>
      <div class="ticket_type">
        <a href="#tab3">Type 1</a>
        <a href="#tab3">Type 2</a>
        <a href="#tab3">Type 3</a>
        <a href="#tab4">Type 4</a>
        <a href="#tab4">Type 5</a>
        <a href="#tab5">Type 6</a>
      </div>
      <button type="button">Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab2" data-level='2'>
    <li>
      <p>Go buy some ticket then</p>
      <button>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab3" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <div class="answer_1">
        <p>Please go to hall A</p>
        <img src="receptionist.png" alt="">
        <button>Back</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab4" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <p>Please go to hall B</p>
      <button>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" id="tab5" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <p>Please go to hall C</p>
      <button>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction ! If you don't mind I want to ask you about animation on JQuery. How can I add an animation where if I press any button the old 'ul' will go fadeout to the left and the new 'ul' will come and fadein from the right side. But if I press the 'Back' button it will do the opposite which is the old 'ul' will fadeout to the right and the new 'ul' will fadein to the left.

Comment: @Kenken - that is a cool idea, but requires a bit of planning and structure and is definitely out of scope from your original question. I suggest marking this as the answer here, and creating a new question. It can be done with jQuery or with Animate.css like you currently have. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Yeah I will open up new queston after this.